# Using maven outside of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am already using maven outside of eclipse, but would like to use Eclipse as my main editor.  I don't want to use the maven already embedded with M2E.  I want to use mine located at /usr/bin/mvn.

Under Window > Preferences, I try to add a maven installation at /usr/bin/mvn (clicking Ok does nothing; stays at the same window) and at /usr/bin (gives the error: `The selected directory is not a valid Maven directory.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your maven where is Maven Home

```
$ mvn -V

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: /home/myuser/maven
```

and in Eclipse add Maven Home to Maven Installation settings.

But better solution is to use Maven distribution from http://maven.apache.org/. Simply unpack this and configure in Eclipse. Maven from system distribution work great with application installed from system and is not good for development.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/mvn` is where the binary is placed, actual maven installation directory might be at `/usr/share/maven`